# How to connect to internet from archlinux and install python

Tags: python, archlinux

I am using an arch-linux image of raspberry-pi with emacspeak.The image was downloaded from the following link.

[Arch image](http://raspberrypi.windowswiki.info/images/emacspeak/2013-04-08-emacspeak-arch/2013-04-08-emacspeak-arch.img.zip)

I need to install python on this image.I tried

```
sudo pacman -S python
```

But it seems like i am not able to connect to internet even though i have connected the ethernet cable.Is there a way to install python offline or to make internet working on the arch-linux image .

Comment: Can you paste the output of ifconfig or ipconfig - I don't remember which is installed on arch.

Comment: It seems both the commands are not installed on this image.I am getting a command not found message

Comment: OK, lets try this to confirm that the network is down, can you ping google.com?

Comment: nope.. Giving response unknown host

Comment: The link you posted above is broken. Can you fix that so I can check that this is supposed to be a complete arch distro?

Comment: To rule out the obvious what is the other end of the Ethernet cable connected to. If a router can you check it's device list?

Comment: I'm so sorry that the link got broken.Also the ethernet cable is fine as i have used the same to connect to my laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20177/discussion-between-slavecoder-and-steve-robillard).

Comment: I have updated the link @SteveRobillard

Comment: Please provide the output of `ip addr` (which is the command that replaces ifconfig)

Comment: even this command is given as command not found

Comment: You might want to try regular raspbian instead.  I'm not VI, but `apt-cache search brltty` shows a number of packages for braille devices and speech drivers.  This may require you upgrade to jessie.

Answer (score 1):

[I've included options using `ifconfig` instead of `ip` below.  If `ifconfig` is not found, you are sort of out of luck; the distribution is missing critical networking tools.]

With the ethernet cable plugged in:

```
ip link
- OR -
ifconfig -a
```

Should show an entry including `eth0`, unless Arch's init renames things (it may), in which case there should be an entry that includes `link/ether` in the description.  Regard that as `eth0` below.

If there's no such entry, check the leds around the jack.  If they are not lit, something's physically wrong or you have a very strange kernel -- try another distro.

Now try:

```
sudo dhclient -r
sudo ip link set eth0 up
- OR -
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Then:

```
sudo dhclient -v eth0
```

You should see a negotiation ending with you getting an IP address.  If so and you still cannot connect, add to `/etc/resolve.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

And try again.